# Unable to trace routes in map | GMap.net | VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, gmap.net

I'm facing a issue where i'm unable to trace routes using any map provider I've chosen, I must be doing something wrong......

Using Google maps I can set markers and create poligons but when I create a route I get status "Request Denied" already tried using API keys and using code to replace URL's from http to https but i still get request denied... Also when i try using a diferent route provider MP needs a few seconds to process but returns empty variable

This is the code I'm using

```
        GMapW.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance
        GMapW.Position = New PointLatLng(40.654331, -73.917067)
        Dim RP As RoutingProvider = DirectCast(GMapW.MapProvider, RoutingProvider)
        Dim P1 As New PointLatLng(40.657161, -73.921079)
        Dim P2 As New PointLatLng(40.65587, -73.915188)
        Dim MP As MapRoute = RP.GetRoute(P1, P2, True, False, Convert.ToInt32(GMapW.Zoom))
        Dim R As New GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapRoute(MP.Points, "Route")
        Dim SB As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(125, 0, 255, 0))
        R.Stroke = New Pen(SB, 6)
        Dim mOverlayRoutes = New GMapOverlay("Routes")
        mOverlayRoutes.Routes.Add(R)
        GMapW.Overlays.Add(mOverlayRoutes)
```

Any tips apreciated...

Comment: Have you tried to issue a HTTPS request to the Google Direction APIs (passing your Key), then build a route using the JSON response? The routing service has changed and GMap.Net is not exactly updated. Maybe you can use [GoogleApi](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi) instead

Comment: Apparently my api key is not valid for Google Direction API... And this api is not free... Is  there any way to use a free api key in gmap.net to trace routes, which type of key should i use?

Comment: You could get route coordinates using a different (free) service, then plot the route using the Google Maps provider, if you prefer that visual representation. It boils down to GPS coordinates, after all. -- Note that the Gmap.Net server-side route builder doesn't work with any provider. You can build a static route from start / end point (using a `GMapRoute` object), but you'll get a straight line if you don't provide all the points yourself.

Comment: Thanks I managed to trace a strait line linking the points but do you know if its possible to get the route or points of route from another service or api and import into GMapRoute

Comment: Yes, it's possible; as mentioned, these are all geolocations. The *problem* is that most routing services require paid subscriptions. E.g., OpenStreetMap is a free (Open Source) service, but if you want to generate a route, you have to subscribe to a service that uses its data to generate the route. These third-party services are usually paid. If you find one that isn't...

Comment: I'm gonna explain my app ... I've go a SQL db with some tables and some of them include a Lat and Long GPS coordinates now these represent pickups and deliveries from a truck now I need to represent the approximate path the truck took from one pickup to the next... I suppose that it doesn't simplify the issue... but since the route is in the past I just need to connect each two points using roads